# Properly include a project with .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to compile some C# code with .NET Core. My [last attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42704911/347964) was hindered by YamlDotNet not supporting .NET Core, but that [has changed](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/180).

So, I set up a project like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\YamlDotNet\YamlDotNet\YamlDotNet.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETCoreApp</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I ran:

```
dotnet restore
```

That was successful. Then I tried:

```
dotnet build
```

This yielded the following error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1111,5):
  error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0"
  were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this
  framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for
  which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be
  resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
  reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for
  the framework you intend.
  [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5):
  error : Cannot find project info for '/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj'.
  This can indicate a missing project reference.
  [/work/yaml-editor/docker/src/dotnet/dotnet.csproj]
```

I am using the official `microsoft/dotnet:1.0-sdk` docker container, so I don't understand why `.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0` is missing. How can I fix the error?

**Update:**

I figured out that I have to configure `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.3</TargetFramework>` which is also present in `YamlDotNet.csproj`. However, now I get this error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset". [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Core/YamlException.cs(113,30): error CS0115: 'YamlException.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)': no suitable method found to override [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Core/YamlException.cs(112,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Permissions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Core/YamlException.cs(112,57): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Permissions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Core/YamlException.cs(112,112): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Flags' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Core/YamlException.cs(112,120): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Permissions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Serialization/Utilities/TypeConverter.cs(45,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Permissions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Serialization/Utilities/TypeConverter.cs(45,52): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Permissions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Serialization/Utilities/TypeConverter.cs(45,107): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
Serialization/Utilities/TypeConverter.cs(47,54): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'TypeConverter' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Cannot find project info for '/work/yaml-editor/docker/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet/YamlDotNet.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference. [/work/yaml-editor/docker/src/dotnet/dotnet.csproj]
make: *** [build/bin/dotnet-event] Error 1
```

I remember to have seen similar errors when I last tried this, but I wonder why it still happens, since YamlDotNet claims to support .NET Core.

Comment: Did you try `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>`?

Comment: @JoséPedro yes, that does not work because `YamlDotNet.csproj` has the `<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>` / `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` combo configured, so if I use what you propose, I get an error about mismatching target frameworks.

Comment: Did you try swapping the `PropertyGroup` and the `ItemGroup`?

Comment: @JoséPedro that seems to be irrelevant. Added update to question.

Comment: Try running `dotnet restore` again.

Comment: Tried, doesn't help.

Comment: You can only refer projects as Net Standard, or Nuget Packages. Class Lib doen't work with .Net Core

Comment: @Fals But I want to be able to use the current development version of YamlDotNet if necessary. Is this not possible?

Comment: @flyx you can, but if It's .Net Standard. The updated error refers to a not implemented version of Permissions on .Net Standard 1.3, you could probly try to bump to v1.6 that has more stuff ported to.

Comment: okay, I'll try that. tomorrow.

Comment: Please update to a recent version of the .NET Core SDK. The version you are using (1.0.1) has been superseded by 1.1.0 and 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, which I resolved by adding:

```
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;
```

Try adding one of the four namespaces and see which works:

```
using YamlDotNet.Serialization
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel
using YamlDotNet.Helpers
using YamlDotNet.Core
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm afraid this project is long gone and I can't verify whether this was the problem.